# Unsicher über den Satzbau in folgendem Text

Tags: sentence-structure

Folgender Text muss in einer App angezeigt werden (Beschreibung einer Funktion):

> Versendet in bestimmten Zeitabständen die aktuelle Geo-Position per SMS.

Ich bin mir nicht ganz sicher, ob der Satzbau so i.O. ist.

Comment: Der Satzbau is korrekt, aber SMS sollte als Abkürzung groß geschrieben werden. Was ist eine *Geo-Position*?

Comment: An welchen Stellen bist du dir beim Satzbau unsicher?

Comment: @RolandIllig es heißt doch, dass das "Wo", also "in bestimmten Zeitabständen" immer am Ende stehen soll. Klingt aber komisch.

Comment: "In Frankreich" wäre ein Wo, *in bestimmten Zeitabständen* dagegen nicht. Das ist ein Wann.

Comment: habe ich auch gemeint, es war zuspät zu ändern...

Answer (score 4):

So, wie er jetzt ist, hat der Satz die perfekte Reihenfolge.

> Versendet in bestimmten Zeitabständen die aktuelle Geo-Position per SMS.

In der jetzigen Reihenfolge wird erst ein Zeitpunkt definiert, der dann mit „aktuelle“ referenziert wird. Dadurch wird unterstrichen, dass die *jeweils* aktuelle Position übertragen wird.

Man könnte das *Was* vor das *Wann* stellen, damit die Zeitangabe später im Satz steht. Das wäre aber nicht gut, denn dann kommt das Wort „aktuelle“ zu früh:

> Versendet die aktuelle Geo-Position in bestimmten Zeitabständen per SMS.

Hier wird (möglicherweise) einmal am Anfang die aktuelle Position bestimmt, und dann wird sie wiederholt verschickt. Da das offensichtlich unsinnig ist, ist es auch unwahrscheinlich, dass jemand den Satz falsch interpretiert.

Answer (score 3):

Der Satzbau ist vollkommen in Ordnung. (SMS sollte man groß schreiben, wie Janka schon sagte.) Man könnte noch überlegen, ob statt "Geo-Position" besser "Geoposition" zu schreiben wäre. Das Wort ist inzwischen so alltäglich, dass ich auf den Bindestrich (der die Wortbestandteile auseinanderzuhalten hilft) vielleicht inzwischen verzichten würde. Allerdings wird jemand, der das Wort (noch) nicht kennt, schnell mit dem Argument bei der Hand sein, man brauche den Bindestrich, um sich das Wort aus seinen Teilen erklären zu können. Nun gut. Eine Frage der Gewöhnung. Wir schreiben auch nicht mehr "Fahr-Stuhl".